# Referencing non-written rulings

Tags: discussion

Again, related to the [game-of-thrones-card-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones-card-game) - the rule set for this game was not very well defined and due to the large card pool, certain interactions are not easy to rule upon.

The community usually relies on the rulings of very well known players (former world champions etc) to explain how these things work. How would we go about referencing their rulings, especially if they are littered throughout facebook groups, skype chats, dedicated forums and other places which are not generally accessible directly to the public without registration?

Answer (score 3):

I would say you need to at the very least summarize (or quote) the source, state who it is that is providing the ruling, and what standing they have to issue that ruling. An example of this would be my answer on the question [Is it possible for a person to lose “Pirate Islands” Seafarers scenario before the game even starts?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/is-it-possible-for-a-person-to-lose-pirate-islands-seafarers-scenario-before-t/24056#24056), where one of the people that works on the game offers a fix for the asker's problem.

If at all possible link to the location of a ruling, if it is somewhere that requires registration note that with the link, something like:

> [Reference](http://www.example.com) (requires registration to view)